# Mysql Insert into to copy data

Tags: php, mysql

i try to copy records from one table to another table of other database

what i try

```
    $sql13 = " INSERT INTO `archive_accounts`.`bank_info` SELECT * FROM
   `pb_accounts`.`bank_info` WHERE `emp_id` = '$seid' ";
    mysqli_query($dbac,$sql13);
```

and many other queries all of them run properly but

```
    $sql21 = " INSERT INTO `archive_accounts`.`compensation` SELECT * FROM `pb_accounts`.`compensation` WHERE `emp_id` = '$seid' ";
        mysqli_query($dbac,$sql21) or die(mysqli_error($dbac));
```

and

```
  $sql17 = " INSERT INTO `archive_accounts`.`c_allowance` SELECT * FROM `pb_accounts`.`c_allowance` WHERE `emp_id` = '$seid' ";
        mysqli_query($dbac,$sql17) or die(mysqli_error($dbac));
```

not copying any row and not throwing any error the table structure are same when i use phpmyadmin to run query it run properly

table structure of `pb_accounts`.`c_allowance`

```
id  int(11)

 emp_id int(11)

allowance decimal(9,2)
```

date date

table structure of `pb_accounts`.`c_allowance` and `archive_accounts`.`c_allowance`

```
id  int(11)

 emp_id int(11)

allowance decimal(9,2)
```

date date

structure of `archive_accounts`.`compensation` and `pb_accounts`.`c_allowance`

```
 id  int(11)

 emp_id int(11)

 amount  int(11)

 approved_by varchar(75)

 detail  varchar(100)

 date   date
```

Comment: is `id` an auto-increment column in `archive_accounts`?

Comment: no `id` is auto increment in `pb_accounts` not in `archive_accounts`

Comment: are you sure that the condition is working?

Comment: Can you use `desc table tablename`?

Answer (score 0):

**"ambiguous column reference"** might make problems when the SELECT and the INSERT refer to the same table or feild name. try using **alias**

Comment: but when i run it by phpmyadmin query editor it run properly and copy data why it's not run by php